# How do I prevent the audio controls from disappearing in iOS UIWebView?

Tags: ios, html, uiwebview, html5-audio

We are using a UIWebView in our app and we supply some audio to the view through the HTML 5 audio tag.  The audio plays and works well, but our problem is that about 4-5 seconds into playback, the controls fade away and you have to tap the screen area to show the controls again.  I'm thinking the audio control is reusing the video control code where it makes sense to hide the controls during playback, but when using an audio control and the only thing visible are the controls, it seems like they should stay on screen.

This is what the code looks like:

```
<p style='display: none'>Audio Message</p>
<audio style='display: block; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px' width='200' controls='controls'>
    <source src='audio-test-file.mp4' type='audio/mp4'/>
</audio>
```

The file is technically an MPEG4 video with a single frame at the beginning showing a static image, but in this instance, we're simply playing the audio. I wonder if this is confusing the audio controller into thinking it's a video and therefore it hides the controls.

Is there a way to get the controls to stay on the screen for the duration of the audio playback?

Comment: My guess is the fact that you're using a video file is the problem. Works fine for me with an mp3.

Answer (score 1):

As suspected, the video frame in the MP4 was causing the problem.  I was able to generate audio without the video and the playback controls remain on screen for the duration of the message.

Thanks to Kevin Ennis for actually trying it with an MP3 file.